# Mockito:how to match Class<T>

Tags: mockito, match

I have a question what about Argument Matcher.

```
class A(){
   public B method(Class T,String str){} 
}
```

I Stub the method and want pass the method.but .

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
>   Invalid use of argument matchers!

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
Mockito.doReturn(b).when(a).method(argThat(new IsClass)), "111");
```

Class IsClass:

```
class IsClass extends ArgumentMatcher<Class> {  
    public boolean matches(Object obj) {  
        return true;  
    }  
}
```

So, how should I do, can pass this method.Thankyou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full exception message should tell you what is wrong:

> This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
>
> //incorrect:
>       someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");

So, if your `isClass()` were a valid ArgumentMatcher then you would stub like this:

```
Mockito.doReturn(b).when(a).method(argThat(new IsClass()), eq("111"));
//note how the second parameter of method uses the argument matcher
//"eq" rather than the raw string "111"
```

Moreover, if you merely want to match "any class object" you can do it like this without having to write your own custom matcher:

```
Mockito.doReturn(b).when(a).method(any(Class.class), eq("111"));
```

Finally, you can only stub for mocks. So your test would have to include some setup code like this:

```
A a = Mockito.mock(A.class);
B b = new B();
Mockito.doReturn(...
```

Consider spending some time reading through [the documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.18/org/mockito/Mockito.html) to get a better handle of how to test using Mockito.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, you help me to solve the problem.This     Mockito.doReturn(b).when(a).method(any(Class.class), eq("111"));   is very good work.

Comment: @yujia I'm glad it helped. Can you please accept my answer? (green tick)

Comment: sorry,I'm a new member at stack overflow .

Comment: @yujia thank you very much!